# Why the text in canvas can't be centered vertically

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function (
        x,
        y,
        width,
        height,
        radius
    ) {
        if (width < 2 * radius) radius = width / 2;
        if (height < 2 * radius) radius = height / 2;
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        this.arcTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + height, radius);
        this.arcTo(x + width, y + height, x, y + height, radius);
        this.arcTo(x, y + height, x, y, radius);
        this.arcTo(x, y, x + width, y, radius);
        this.closePath();
        return this;
    };

let generateCanvas = function (config) {
        var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var tmpContext = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");
        tmpContext.font = tmpContext.font.replace(/\d+px/, config.fontSize);
        var textWidth = tmpContext.measureText(config.text).width || 10;
        tmpCanvas = null;
        var textCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var textContext = textCanvas.getContext("2d");
        textCanvas.height = config.height;
        textCanvas.width = textWidth;
        textCanvas.width = textWidth + 2 * config.padding;
        textContext.lineWidth = config.lineWidth;
        textContext.strokeStyle = config.lineColor;
        textContext.fillStyle = config.backgroundColor;
        textContext.roundRect(
                0,
                0,
                textCanvas.width,
                textCanvas.height,
                config.rounded
            );
            textContext.stroke();
            textContext.fill();
        textContext.fillStyle = config.color;
        textContext.font = textContext.font.replace(/\d+px/, config.fontSize);
        textContext.textAlign = config.textAlign;
        textContext.textBaseline = config.textBaseline;
        textContext.fillText(
            config.text,
            textCanvas.width / 2,
            config.height / 2
        );
        return textCanvas;
    };
```

The config I passed to the generateCanvas function is:

```
{
                            text: "测试名称测试名称测试名称测试名称",
                            height: 40,
                            fontSize: "24px",
                            textAlign: "center",
                            textBaseline: "middle",
                            color: "#F9A403",
                            backgroundColor: "white",
                            lineColor: "transparent",
                            rounded: 25,
                            padding: 10,
                        }
```

Why is the text in the image generated by the above function not centered vertically? roundRect is a custom function that implements drawing a rectangle with rounded corners using canvas.Please help me if there are any gods to look at this problem.

Comment: And particularly, what's the value of `config.textBaseline`?

Comment: The code [*works for me*](https://jsfiddle.net/3usfmnh9/)

Comment: I get a feeling that alignment was designed for lower-cased roman alphabet https://jsfiddle.net/heldersepu/3mxc61wr/ see the upper case X how top big compared with lower case

Comment: There is some more reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline  but I have a feeling that if you want to do better, you are going to need to create your own way ... measure each character height and place it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The `"middle"` value of `textBaseline` is based on the [em-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)). This means it will work well for latin glyphs, but not so well for ideographic glyphs, which would need an *ideographic centered baseline* value, that the Canvas API doesn't have, yet.

Here is a graphic representation from [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-textbaseline):

[image: The top of the em square is roughly at the top of the glyphs in a font, the hanging baseline is where some glyphs like आ are anchored, the middle is half-way between the top of the em square and the bottom of the em square, the alphabetic baseline is where characters like Á, ÿ, f, and Ω are anchored, the ideographic-under baseline is where glyphs like 私 and 達 are anchored, and the bottom of the em square is roughly at the bottom of the glyphs in a font. The top and bottom of the bounding box can be far from these baselines, due to glyphs extending far outside the em square.]

But all hope is not lost, during the last years, all browsers have made some progress in their implementations of the [TextMetrics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) interface, and we finally have access to enough information from all major browsers to measure the height of the text being measured.
This means that we can implement a truly centered vertical-align, based on the glyphs being rendered:

```js
const text_input = document.querySelector("input[type='text']");
const padding_input = document.querySelector("input[type='range']");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");;
const font = "60px sans-serif";
let padding_x = 10;
let padding_y = 10;

text_input.oninput = padding_input.oninput =
  (evt) => drawText(text_input.value);

drawText(text_input.value);

// returns an easier to use BBox like object
// from a TextMetrics object
function getTextBBox( ctx, text ) {
  const metrics = ctx.measureText( text );
  const left = metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft * -1;
  const top = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent * -1;
  const right = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight;
  const bottom = metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent;
  const width = right - left;
  const height = bottom - top;
  return { left, top, right, bottom, width, height };
}

function drawText( text ) {
  // we set only the font
  // other values like textBaseline and textAlign
  // are left to their default
  ctx.font = font;
  const bbox = getTextBBox(ctx, text);
  const padding = +padding_input.value;
  canvas.width = bbox.width + padding;
  canvas.height = bbox.height + padding;
  ctx.font = font;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#F9A403";

  const middle_x = bbox.left + (bbox.width / 2);
  const middle_y = bbox.top + (bbox.height / 2);
  const left = canvas.width / 2 - middle_x;
  const top = canvas.height / 2 - middle_y;

  ctx.fillText(text, left, top);

  // draw the middle line for reference  
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.height/2-1, canvas.width, 2);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<label>Text content: <input type="text" value="测试名称测试名称测试名称测试名称"></label><br>
<label>Padding: <input type="range" min="0" max="100"></label><br>
<canvas></canvas>
```